# How to find minimum range to put in a specific function

Tags: java, loops

I pretty new to programming and just got enrolled in a college.
So far I've learned some basic loops, but the question is how do i determine the minimum range of a specific function?

Here's the case:
"Choose the first interval by finding a and b such that ()∙()<0 "

and the function that i have to use is: 8−4.5(−sin)=0

Now I was asked to input 2 numbers in that function and multiply it.

Here's example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      double a = sc.nextDouble();
      double b = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.println(function(a)*function(b);

   public static double function(double x) {
      double resultF = 0;
      resultF = 8 - (4.5 * (x - Math.sin(x)));
      return resultF;
}
```

which I already have make a class for it.

Now the problem is how do I find the minimum value if I were to input 2 (function(a)*function(b)) to be as close as zero.

So it begins with making user input 2 random numbers. Then both of them will have to go through 8−4.5(−sin)=0 function. 
After the numbers have been calculated then you take both of that "calculated numbers" and multiplied it together.
 What I am trying to do here is trying to make a loop that would automatically shorter the interval of the "input" and making them as close to zero as possible. (Referring to the 8−4.5(−sin)=0 function)

So far what I can do is:

package com.company;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      double a = sc.nextDouble();
      double b = sc.nextDouble();
      double resultA = function(a);
      double resultB = function(b);
      double newA = 0;
      double newB = 0;

      System.out.println(resultA * resultB);
      System.out.println(resultA*resultB);
      if (resultA*resultB >=0) {
         if(a<b) {
            while(function(a)*function(b)>=0) {
               newA = a++;
               newB = b--;
            }

         } else if(a > b) {
            while(function(a)*function(b)>=0) {
               newA = a--;
               newB = b++;
            }
      }
   }
}
```

I know that minimum interval is 3 and 2 but I don't know how to get my loop work.

Thank you for your replies !

Every Help is appreciated! 
Thank you

Comment: which minimium value?

Comment: soif  i good unserstand you want the shorstest interval were the fontion change of sign?

Comment: What I am trying to do is making a loop that would make the interval as close to 0 as possible. The loop refers to this "8−4.5(−sin)=0" .

Comment: you want to solve aproximately the equation ? get a result that is the closest to the matematical one ?

Comment: or get the intervale that match which is the closest from 0?

Comment: So it begins with making user input 2 random numbers. Then both of them will have to go through 8−4.5(−sin)=0 function. After the numbers have been calculated then you take both of that input and multiplied it together. What I am trying to do here is trying to make a loop that would automatically shorter the interval of the input and making them as close to zero as possible. Thank you for your replies !

Comment: can you give some example ? because in your case you have a bijective function on R so your equation has only one solution that is betwen 2.4 and 2.45 so if the user give you 0 10 you want to get 2.4 2.45 or 0 2.45 ?

Comment: or some some thing shorter like 2.43 2.431 and getting some thing as short as possible

Comment: Yes! My main objective is to get the result around 2.45, but I don't how to make my loops shorten the user input as close to zero as possible.
Thankyou for your reply!

Comment: ok take your code and i will show you

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, but what does it mean to "Take your code"?

Comment: use your code as the base of my reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully answer completely to your question if you want to get the shortest intervalle the intuitive methods is to reduce it by a step defined like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = sc.nextDouble();
    double b = sc.nextDouble();
    double step = sc.nextDouble();
    if (a > b) {
        double tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    double bResult = function(b);
    while (function(a) * bResult < 0) {
        a += step;
    }
    a -= step;
    double aResult = function(a);
    while (aResult * function(b) < 0) {
        b -= step;
    }
    b += step;
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
    System.out.println(function(a) + " " + function(b));
    sc.close();
}
```

but if you want a precise result then the step is little then the computation can be very long ... A solution consists to use Dichotomy . The concept is simple : reduce the interval by divising le range by 2 until the range is shorter than your wanted interval like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = sc.nextDouble();
    double b = sc.nextDouble();
    double step = sc.nextDouble();

    if (a > b) {
        double tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    while (Math.abs(a - b) > step) {
        double mid = (a+b) / 2;
        if (function(mid) == 0) {
            System.out.println(mid);
            return;
        }
        if (function(a) * function(mid) < 0) {
            b = mid;
        } else {
            a = mid;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
    System.out.println(function(a) + " " + function(b));
    sc.close();
}
```

Hoping that's will help you.